# fork: Resource temporarily unavailable - on CentOS server

Tags: process, ulimit, fork

I can't run anything anymore (hardly anything) and I keep getting the following error message. If I execute a command, it can be it comes several times the error *fork: retry: No child processes*, if I test it several times, it works then sometime.

> -bash: fork: retry: No child processes
> -bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Examples of the error message:

```
[user@server ~]$ sudo -i
sudo: unable to fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

[user@server ~]$ sudo -i
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

-bash-4.2#

-bash-4.2# logout

[user@server ~]$ sudo -i

[root@server ~]#

[root@server ~]# ps -e --no-headers | wc -l
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
86

[root@server ~]# man ulimit
man: fork failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

[root@server ~]# ps -eLF
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

All I could research is that no new process can be created because apparently the limit for processes has been reached. On my server there are permanently less than 100 processes running in less than 350 threads.

```
[root@server ~]# ps -e --no-headers | wc -l
86
```

Data from `htop`:

```
Tasks: 86, 311 thr; 1 running
Load average: 0.04 0.17 0.16
```

The limits look high enough for me so far:

```
[root@server ~]# prlimit
RESOURCE   DESCRIPTION                             SOFT      HARD UNITS
AS         address space limit                unlimited unlimited bytes
CORE       max core file size                         0 unlimited blocks
CPU        CPU time                           unlimited unlimited seconds
DATA       max data size                      unlimited unlimited bytes
FSIZE      max file size                      unlimited unlimited blocks
LOCKS      max number of file locks held      unlimited unlimited
MEMLOCK    max locked-in-memory address space  67108864  67108864 bytes
MSGQUEUE   max bytes in POSIX mqueues            819200    819200 bytes
NICE       max nice prio allowed to raise             0         0
NOFILE     max number of open files                1024      4096
NPROC      max number of processes                62987     62987
RSS        max resident set size              unlimited unlimited pages
RTPRIO     max real-time priority                     0         0
RTTIME     timeout for real-time tasks        unlimited unlimited microsecs
SIGPENDING max number of pending signals        1029347   1029347
STACK      max stack size                       8388608 unlimited bytes

[root@server ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1029347
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62987
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

[root@server ~]# ulimit -aH
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1029347
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62987
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

**What else can I check?**
**Or what can be the cause of this misbehavior?**

The server is a rented vServer (VPS); a container in a Virtuozzo environment of the provider.
The server is running CentOS 7.9 and has Plesk installed; so it is running web servers (httpd), mail servers (Postfix, Dovecot).

Can it be a problem from the Virtuozzo environment? If so, is there any way I can validly determine this to approach the provider?